# Nginx Location Passing Issue

Tags: apache, nginx, web, redirect

I'd like to use a nginx proxy to pass certain directorys on my webserver to another directory.

i want example.com/somedirectory/* to send it back to example.com/somedirectory/

How would I do that?

I've tried

```
location /somedirectory/* {

    return 301 https://example.com/somedirectory;
}
```

But this doesn't work.

I also want to avoid having a constant redirect loop when I open example.com/somedirectory.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this using regex:

```
location ~^/somedirectory/(.*)$ {
    return 301 https://example.com/somedirectory;
}
```